# How do you create a window with a title in a developed Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a new chrome window via the Javascript call chrome.app.window.create().  This seems like a common use case, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this in https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create.

Note:  If you set the title of the  tag in the html file, it will show in the taskbar if you hover over it, but I can not get anything to show in the title bar.

Using Chrome on Windows.

```
chrome.app.window.create('<html file>', {
            ...
            resizable: false,
            frame: {
                type: 'chrome',
                color: '#1B609B',
                inactiveColor: '#15E0EF'
            }
        });
```

Comment: You mean in the top frame?

Comment: I believe so, like this:  http://spacecitytech.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/computertitleshake.jpg.  Not sure if that is part of the top frame or not.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not possible with the native frame.

Comment: cant you do it from within the page javascript?